# Inequality $|\exp(i \xi \cdot x) - \exp(i \xi \cdot y) | \leq C |x-y|^\alpha |\xi|^\alpha,$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

I am reading a proof of a theorem. In that proof there is the following inequality without proof

$$|\exp(i \xi \cdot x) - \exp(i \xi \cdot y) | \leq C |x-y|^\alpha |\xi|^\alpha,$$

where $0<\alpha<1$ is given, $x,y,\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $C$ is a positive constant which not depend of $x,y,\xi$.

How can I prove that inequality?. Can you help me, please?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, $$|e^{iz}-1| \leq \min\{2,|z|\} \tag{1}$$ for any $z \in \mathbb{R}$. If $\alpha \in (0,1]$, then $$|w| \leq |w|^{\alpha} \qquad \text{for all $|w| \leq 1$}$$ and $$1 \leq |w|^{\alpha} \quad \text{for all $|w|>1$}.$$ Using these estimates for $w:=\frac{z}{2}$ we get $$|e^{iz}-1| \leq \min \left\{2 \left| \frac{z}{2} \right|^{\alpha}, 2 \left| \frac{z}{2} \right|^{\alpha} \right\} = 2^{1-\alpha} |z|^{\alpha}. \tag{2}$$ Thus, $$|e^{i \xi \cdot x}-e^{i \xi \cdot y}| = |e^{i \xi \cdot (x-y)}-1| \leq 2^{1-\alpha} |\xi \cdot (x-y)|^{\alpha} \leq 2^{1-\alpha} |\xi|^{\alpha} |x-y|^{\alpha}.$$

Comment: The inequality $(1)$ has a typo, right? Should be $|e^{iz} - 1|$.

Comment: @ViniciusNovelli Yes, thank you!

Comment: The factor $2$ is not needed.

Comment: The first inequality is not obvious and not the strictest one. The obvious intermediate steps give $$|e^{iz}-1|=2\sin(|z|/2)\le \min(2, |z|).$$

Comment: But even then the constant in the bound $2⋅|z/2|^α=2^{1-α}⋅|z|^α$ contains a slightly reduced factor $2$.

Comment: @Did I'm well aware of that but I thought it would be easier to prove this way (... and, moreover, the OP wasn't asking for the optimal constant).

Comment: @LutzL Well, $\min (2,|z|) \leq 2 \min (1,|z|) $ is quite obviois, isn't it? (The "obvious intermediate steps" depend on the person you are asking; I would prove it a different way.)

Comment: To me, your (1) is not so clear while (1') $|e^{ix}-1|\leqslant\min\{2,|x|\}$ would be direct, using the uniform bound $1$ on the modulus of the derivative. Matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: @Did I see, I'll edit my answer later.